# VBA run macro only once

Tags: excel, vba

Im running below macro when worksheet is opened. The problem is that whenever I change value in cell or perform any event the macro starts again. How to prevent it?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim i As Long

i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range([W2], Cells(Rows.Count,  "W").End(xlUp)), "tak")
Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("AZ1").Value = i
If Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("AZ1").Value > 0 Then
MsgBox "Sa " & i & " wózki do przeglądu"
Else
MsgBox "Nie ma wózków do przeglądu"
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as opening worksheets (as far as I know). Use the `Worksheet_Activate` event instead of `Worksheet_Calculate` if you want the macro to be performed when you switch to the worksheet.

You also might need to add something like

```
 If ActiveSheet.Name = "sheetnamehere" Then yourMacroHere
```

to the `Workbook_Open` event if you want the macro to be executed if the sheet is active when the workbook is opened.

I recommend to move the code to a separate macro and call that macro from the event(s).